# Laravel DOMDocument : failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I'm trying to generate xml file in Laravel, I use DOMdocument but I got this error message when I try to save the file :

```
DOMDocument::save(result.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproj/resources/views/feed/index.blade.php)
```

Code in blade file :

```
    @php 
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
  $dom->formatOutput = true;

  $root = $dom->createElement('student');
  $dom->appendChild($root);

  $result = $dom->createElement('result');
  $root->appendChild($result);

  $result->setAttribute('id', 1);
  $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('name', 'Opal Kole') );
  $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('sgpa', '8.1') );
  $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('cgpa', '8.4') );

  echo '<xmp>'. $dom->saveXML() .'</xmp>';
  $dom->save('result.xml') or die('XML Create Error');
@endphp
```

I know it's something with permission but i'm not sure where to change the permission and for what. Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to provide writeble path to save method, like
`$dom->save(storage_path('result.xml'))`

Comment: Nice. Thank you !:)

Answer (score 0):

In which directory/Folder you create "result.xml" file, that directory you should give 775 permission

then run below command

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

OR

```
php artisan config:clear
```